# How can I force keyboard shortcuts on a video player?

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, getelementbyid

I use a certain hub website using only one hand and for some years now this certain website make things akward for me when using some keyboard shortcuts to play/pause and seek in the video.

**Problem:**
I open many tabs from this website at the same time and also I change between them frequently. Whenever I change tabs and interact with a video on another tab, the video from the player in previous tab loses focus and the only way to make the shortcuts work again is by click on the video. Which is difficult when using one hand, since I have to move from the keyboard to the mouse.

Can someone give me tips on how to solve this very specific problem?

I've tried the code below but it didn't work:

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');

 window.addEventListener('touchstart', function videoStart() {
   video.play();
   // remove from the window and call the function we are removing
   this.removeEventListener('touchstart', videoStart);
 });
```

Comment: You're not making sense... **(1)** How did you try using the above shown code if you're **not the owner** of the website? **(2)** Do you know how to get the direct video **file** links from the site? A possible solution could be to make a Chrome Extension (using JS code) that detects mouse clicks on these links but it also does a `preventDefault` to avoid going to a new page, but you'll now know where the link was pointing to and then use your own code (might need PHP) to extract the video link and open it a new tab... Video files that are opened in their own tabs have constant focus.